# How to use User-defined @variable as thread safe in Mysql

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, thread-safety

When accessing @variable in mysql using same connection object from spring framework. It is common for all the users, so looks like not thread-safe variable to use in the query. How to use @variable of alternatives for user defined variable in mysql.

Alternative query for below one with thread safe in the same connection object.

```
select
@num := (@num + 1) as row_number
from
user u,
(select @num := 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including `(select @num := 0)` initializes the variable at the beginning of the query.  User-defined variables are scoped to the individual connection, and a connection can only run one query at a time, so this specific case is perfectly "thread-safe."

However, it's also a bit of a hack.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html